# Gson: Deserialize Json into Abstract Class

Tags: java, json

I have json that contains:

```
{"timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"}
```

among many other keys, and I want to deserialize it into `java.util.TimeZone`. `TimeZone` is just a field in a class that I want to instantiate with this json.

The issue is that `TimeZone` is an abstract class and it should be instantiated with:

```
public static synchronized TimeZone getTimeZone(String ID) {
        return getTimeZone(ID, true);
```

which uses a concrete class `ZoneInfo` to instantiate. The deserializer, however, calls the constructor of `TimeZone` by default. So I got:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public java.util.TimeZone() with no args
```

I wonder how to configure Gson to instantiate a `TimeZone` from the above json?

Comment: have you try using non-abstract class like SimpleTimeZone?

Comment: Id risk saying this isnt possible. The serializer needs to instantiate to build the output value and abstract classes cant be instantiated.

Comment: @JAVAC That's from a library class, which I cannot change unfortunately.

Comment: @Felype But `ZoneInfo` extends `TimeZone`, and I just want to call the right method in `TimeZone` to get the instance, which is a TimeZone.

Comment: Make an empty non-abstract class extending the abstract class you want to deserialize and then deserialize into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to create something like a Gson `TypeAdapter` and register it with your `Gson` instance.

I'm not sure how/whether this will work for your particular data format, but here's an example that I've used in my own projects:

```
public class TimeZoneAdapter extends TypeAdapter<TimeZone> {
  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, TimeZone value) throws IOException {
    out.value(value.getID());
  }

  @Override
  public TimeZone read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    return TimeZone.getTimeZone(in.nextString());
  }
}
```

You would then register it when building a `Gson` instance like so:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(TimeZone.class, new TimeZoneAdapter());

Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Hope this helps!